# Excel VBA PasteSpecial with xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to get a code that I generated using the macro recorder to work. The spreadsheet I'm using has some columns that should only contain numbers or dates, but, for some reason, some of the values as stored as text.

To solve it, I decided to copy and paste adding `0` to all those cells. If I do it by hand, it works fine. So, I started Excel macro recorder to get the code. I did some modification to the code generated, just to make it more readable and clean, but actually, nor the original code nor my version of it work.

The code is as follows:

```
Range("F1").Value = 0
Range("F1").Copy
Set rngPaste = Range(Range("D3:E3"), Range("D3:E3").End(xlDown))
rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, 
                                             _ SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Set rngPaste = Range(Range("G3:J3"), Range("G3:J3").End(xlDown))
rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, 
                                             _ SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe exactly what happens when you run the above code? What do you mean that it doesn't work? Can you add what was recorded before you modified it?

Comment: You say "some of the values as stored as text" so why don't you select them all and format them as default or number?

Comment: @Mike It should change the dates and numbers that are stored as text to their correct type.

Comment: @Peh I have to do it to many Workbooks throughout the time, so It's very appropriate to have a macro to do that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding zero try this *(it worked on my test)*

```
With Range(Range("D3:E3"), Range("D3:E3").End(xlDown))
    .Value = .Value2
End With
With Range(Range("G3:J3"), Range("G3:J3").End(xlDown))
    .Value = .Value2
End With
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you!